# Why unsupported clone() method was added to java.lang.ref.Reference in Java 11

Tags: java, java-11

I was going through the list of Java 11 API changes and this one confuses me a lot:

- The Reference class does not implement the Cloneable interface
- The method will always throw a CloneNotSupportedException

**JDK Changeset**

> 8201793: (ref) Reference object should not support cloning

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/rev/e3653598e3b0

**Reference.clone() Source Code**

```
    /**
    * Throws {@link CloneNotSupportedException}. A {@code Reference} cannot be
    * meaningfully cloned. Construct a new {@code Reference} instead.
    *
    * @returns never returns normally
    * @throws  CloneNotSupportedException always
    *
    * @since 11
    */
    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
    }
```

I'm assuming there must be a reason for its inclusion, probably for something in the future?

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8202260

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis link has the answer

Comment: Overriding methods to emphasize their unsupported nature is not so unusual. Besides adding the new behavior of unconditionally throwing, it also serves as a place for documentation. I suppose, also declaring that method final has been considered too radical…